# What information does PayPal provide to vendors?

Tags: privacy, security, paypal, ecommerce

When paying for services with PayPal, what information does the seller have about the purchaser?  Name?  Country?

From their privacy policy:

> Customer Service: for customer service purposes, including to help
>   service your accounts or resolve disputes (e.g., billing or
>   transactional).
>
> Shipping: in connection with shipping and related services for
>   purchases made using PayPal.
>
> Legal Compliance: to help them comply with anti-money laundering and
>   counter-terrorist financing verification requirements.
>
> Service Providers: to enable service providers under contract with us
>   to support our business operations, such as fraud prevention, bill
>   collection, marketing, customer service and technology services. Our
>   contracts dictate that these service providers only use your
>   information in connection with the services they perform for us and
>   not for their own benefit.

which seems to mean everything with everyone, maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not everything with everyone. That would be wrong and insane

Here's from official documentation: (click on link to see everything, I'll just quote up a few paragraphs)

[**WITH OTHER PAYPAL USERS**](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full#How_We_Share_Personal_Information_with_Other_PayPal_Users)

> When transacting with others, we may provide those parties with
>   information about you necessary to complete the transaction, such as
>   your name, account ID, contact details, shipping and billing address,
>   or other information needed to promote the reliability and security of
>   the transaction. If a transaction is held, fails, or is later
>   invalidated, we may also provide details of the unsuccessful
>   transaction. To facilitate dispute resolution, we may provide a buyer
>   with the seller’s address so that goods can be returned to the seller.
>   The receiving party is not allowed to use this information for
>   unrelated purposes, such as to directly market to you, unless you have
>   agreed to it. Contacting users with unwanted or threatening messages
>   is against our policies and constitutes a violation of our User
>   Agreement.
>
> If someone is sending you money and enters your email address or phone
>   number, we will provide them your registered name so they can verify
>   they are sending the money to the correct account.

[**WITH THIRD PARTIES**](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full#How_We_Share_Personal_Information_with_Other_Third_Parties)

> Members of the PayPal corporate family, such as PayPal Credit, Venmo
>   or Braintree, to provide joint content, products, and services (such
>   as registration, transactions and customer support), to help detect
>   and prevent potentially illegal acts and violations of our policies,
>   and to guide decisions about their products, services, and
>   communications. Members of our corporate family will use this
>   information to send you marketing communications only if you have
>   requested their services. Financial institutions that we partner with
>   to jointly create and offer a product (including but not limited to,
>   the PayPal Extras credit card where we share information with
>   Synchrony Bank, for example, in connection with pre-approved offers
>   for the PayPal Extras credit card). These financial institutions may
>   only use this information to market PayPal-related products, unless
>   you have given consent for other uses.

Comment: It seems ridiculous you could call PayPal and request the name of the business account holder of whom you've done a transaction with. It shows business name not full name for a reason.